# Segmentation fault: 11 while printing dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a simple C++ code where I define a dynamic array as:

```
std::vector<double>IPWeights;
```

and then pass it to a function called reference with a reference (so I changed its content) like:

```
void reference (std::vector<double> &IPWeights)
```

and then in my main function, after I changed my arrays content I wanted to print it like:

```
int size_weights=IPWeights.size();

for (int i=0; i<size_weights; i++)
{
    std::cout<<IPWeights[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

but in the screen I only see "segmentation fault 11".

where the reference is simply looks like:

```
void reference( std::vector<double> &IPWeights)
{
    IPWeights[0]=0.4500;
    IPWeights[1]=0.2648;
    IPWeights[2]=0.2648;
    IPWeights[3]=0.2648;
    IPWeights[4]=0.2519;
    IPWeights[5]=0.2519;
    IPWeights[6]=0.2519;
}
```

Any advice is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Anyone knows why that is??"_ Seems not from the code you're actually showing. Make a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Change int to size_t for size_weights. It can solve your problem.

Comment: @Sergey thanks, but it did not help :(

Comment: `Anyone knows why that is??` most likely due to a bug in your code.

Comment: It probably means that `reference`, or some other code you haven't shown us, is trying to access an element beyond the vector's size (or possibly that the size is too large for `int` - use `size_t` or an iterator). But there's no way to guess why that's happening from the code you've shown us. Use your debugger, or a tool like Valgrind, to find exactly where the segfault happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My crystal ball says that you don't allocate memory for the vector. You should do one of the following:

- Initialize vector with appropriate size:

  ```
  std::vector<double> IPWeights(size_you_need);
  ```
- Call `IPWeights.resize()` before assigning to it:

  ```
  std::vector<double> IPWeights;
  IPWeights.resize(size_you_need);
  ```
- Call `IPWeights.push_back()` instead of assigning by index:

  ```
  IPWeights.push_back(0.4500);
  IPWeights.push_back(0.2648);
  //...
  ```

Comment: Used the 3rd option because I wanted my code to be more generic, and using push_back rather than index is worked, thanks :)