# Segmentation fault 11 when using vectors in C++ concordance program

Tags: c++, macos, vector, segmentation-fault

For starters, total C++ and coding noob here, apologies in advance.  I've been working on a program that creates a concordance of a text file with the number of times a word occurs and on what lines the word occurs on.  Brief example of the intended output:

A occurs 9 time(s) on lines 1 3 5

AND occurs 3 time(s) on lines 2 4

I first wrote the program using only arrays, which I've got running successfully.  I'm now trying to rewrite it using vectors instead of arrays, and basically I have no idea what I'm doing past declaring the vectors.  I've got my vector version to compile and link without errors, but when I run it I get a "segmentation fault 11" error.  From what I understand, the reason this error is occurring because I'm trying to access memory that hasn't been allocated yet.  I'm pasting my entire code that I've written so far below.  If someone can help me out, or point me in the right director of what I need to do to make this happen, that'd be so awesome.  I know I'll need to push the push_back method, but I just have no idea where.  I realize this probably rudimentary to most of you, but I'm just trying to wrap my head around all of this.  Again, thanks so much -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std;

void copy(vector<int> fromarr, vector< vector<int> > toarr, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= fromarr[0]; i++)
    {
        toarr[index][i] = fromarr[i];
    }
}

void copy(vector< vector<int> > fromarr, vector<int> toarr, int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= fromarr[index][0]; i++)
    {
        toarr[i] = fromarr[index][i];
    }
}


int search(vector<string> array, int len, string target)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == target) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void sort(vector<string> wordarray, vector<int> linecount, vector< vector<int> >   linenumbersarray, int length)
{
    int minpos = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        minpos = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if(wordarray[j] > wordarray[minpos]) minpos = j;
            string tempword = wordarray[i];
            int tempcount = linecount[i];
            vector<int> tempnums;
            copy(linenumbersarray, tempnums, i);

            wordarray[i] = wordarray[minpos];
            linecount[i] = linecount[minpos];
            copy(linenumbersarray[minpos], linenumbersarray, i);

            wordarray[minpos] = tempword;
            linecount[minpos] = tempcount;
            copy(tempnums, linenumbersarray, minpos);
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    vector<string> wordarray;

    vector<int> linecount;

    vector< vector<int> > linenumbersarray;

    int arrayposition = 0;

    int linenumber = 1;

    int wordlength = 0;


    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);

    string aline;
    while (getline(infile, aline))
    {

        istringstream theline(aline);
        string aword;

        while (theline >> aword)
        {

            int isupdated = search(wordarray, wordlength, aword);
            if (isupdated == -1)
            {
                wordarray[wordlength] = aword;
                linecount[wordlength] = 1;
                linenumbersarray[wordlength][0] = 1;
                linenumbersarray[wordlength][1] = linenumber;
                wordlength = wordlength + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                linecount[isupdated] = linecount[isupdated] + 1;
                if (linenumbersarray[isupdated][linenumbersarray[isupdated][0]] != linenumber)
                    (linenumbersarray[isupdated][++linenumbersarray[isupdated][0]] = linenumber);
            }

        }
        linenumber = linenumber + 1;
    }

    sort(wordarray, linecount, linenumbersarray, wordlength);


    for (int i = 0; i < wordlength; i++)
    {
        ostringstream out;
        for (int j = 1; j <= linenumbersarray[i][0]; j++)
        {
            out << linenumbersarray[i][j];
            j != linenumbersarray[i][0] ? out << " " : out << ".";
        }
        cout << wordarray[i] << " occurs " << linecount[i] << " time(s) on lines " << out.str() << endl;
        out.flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: First impressions: you want to pass vectors etc around by reference or const reference, not as the whole structures, and rather than vector-of-vector you probably want a map to vector, or better still a map of string to a class or structure that contains its count and the list of lines it appears on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault: 11 while printing dynamic arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400767/segmentation-fault-11-while-printing-dynamic-arrays)

Comment: You need to learn what *references* in C++ are, how to use them, and how iterator-based algorithms are often preferential in modern C++ programs. Most of the code in this is either redundant to functions already supplied in the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) or outright not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

How do you populate your vectors? **Use push_back function** to fill them in.

```
vector<int> v; // an empty container
v.push_back(10); // now it has one element - an integer 10
```

**Use size() function** to access a vector size, **do not pass length parameter** as you do in few functions (sort, search).

Another way to iterate through an stl container (vector is a container) is to **use iterators**.

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{ int a = *it; /*gives you an element of the container*/ }
```

Using size or iterators will prevent you from accessing unallocated memory - **this is your problem**.

Do not use operator [] without checking vector boundary.

```
if (i < v.size()) {v[i]; //an element}
```

Here are two variants of your search function

```
int search(vector<string> const &array, string const &target)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if(array[i] == target) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

vector<string>::const_iterator search(vector<string> const &array, string const &target)
{
    for(vector<string>::const_iterator it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it == target) return it;
    }
    return array.end();
}
```

A better way of searching is to use std::find function, but you may leave that for later when you are more comfortable with STL. std::find does the same as second variant of search above.

```
vector<string>::iterator it;
it = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), target);
if (it != myvector.end())
    std::cout << "Element found in myvector: " << *it << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "Element not found in myvector\n";
```